# Definition of Path in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, definition

One of the definitions for a path in Graph theory is :

> A path (of length r) in a graph G = (V,E) is a sequence $v_0,...,v_r ∈ V$ of vertices such that  $v_{i-1} −v_i ∈ E$  for all  $i = 1,...,r$

It might be a bit of a dumb question but I'm having a trouble understanding this notation.What does $v_{i-1} −v_i$ mean in this context? How can you subtract one vertex from another?

Comment: The line is supposed to be just that here, a line, not a minus sign. In other words, replaces that part with "... such that there is an edge with $v_{i-1}$ and $v_i$ as its two endpoints"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to think about it easier, you can mentally replace that notation with the notation $(v_{i-1},v_{i}) \in E$.  Then if $G$ is not a directed graph, $(v_{i-1},v_{i})$ is pair of vertices forming an edge. And if $G$ is a directed graph, $(v_{i-1},v_{i})$ is an *ordered* pair